# Only Allow ForeignKey Selection of User Values

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a form, where a user can select a foreignkey from a drop down menu.  However, I can't seem to find a way to limit the foreignkey values to those associated with the logged in user.

For example,

Models.py

```
class Site(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

When I pass the ModelForm to the template, a drop down list is generated with ALL the trip values.  How do i get a drop down list to only contain the trip values of a specific logged in user instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class SiteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Site

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(SiteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['trip'].queryset = Trip.objects.filter(id__in=user.site_set.values_list(trip, flat=True))
```

and in the view,

```
form = SiteForm(user=request.user)
```

Comment: change `'trip'` to the appropriate field name you have specified